# Как пройти по всем каталогам и файлам в linux

Tags: linux, поиск, find

Подскажите как пройтись по все каталогам и файлам в скрипте  `bash`. До сегодня использовал `find`

```
for file in $(find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME")
do
    echo $file
do
```

И все прекрасно работало, но если в имени встречаются пробелы то вывод портится. Место полного пути выводится часть имени до пробела а в следующем цикле выводится следующая часть имен  до пробела. В мануале узнал про ключ `-print0` для `find` и гугл сказал что используя этот ключ то вывод должен быть полным, включая пробелы. Но при использовании ключа `-print0` вывод никак не изменился. Пришел к вывод что лучше переименовать такие файлы и папки `rename 's'/ /_/g'` но как только меняется имя каталога то и `find` уже не может найти дальше файлы так как данные в переменных `$TR_TORRENTDIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME` осталось прежним с пробелами. Была идея создать еще 1 переменную в которой будет хранится полный путь только уже не с пробелами а с `_` место пробелов и создать еще 1 цикл и пройтись по всем файлам снова.  Но идея рушится как только будет 2 каталога с пробелами.

Так вот, вопрос, как можно пройти по всем файлам и папкам что что есть внутри и желательно сделать это по очереди, от первого файла к последнему.

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что цикл for принудительно делит всё по пробелам, придётся вместо него использовать что-нибудь другое https://stackoverflow.com/q/8677546

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за внимательность) но Fat-Zer дал прям четкий ответ который работает) за что я ему благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно это делается с помощью цикла `while`.

Если в именах файлов нет переводов строк, нет обратных слешей и нет начальных/конечных пробелов, то достаточно сделать нечто такое:

```
find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" | while read f; do 
  echo "$f"
done
```

Если всё это есть, то можно использовать или ключ `-exec` `find`'а:

```
find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -exec echo '{}' \;
```

Или даже в таком варианте:

```
find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -exec sh -c 'echo "$0"' '{}' \;
```

Или более безопасный вариант предыдущего цикла `while`:

```
find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do 
  echo "$f"
done
```

- `-print0` и `-d ''` — используют в качестве разделителей нулевые символы нулевые символы
- `IFS=` — не даёт `read` отрезать от строки начальные/конечные пробелы
- `-r` — не даёт `read` интерпретировать обратные слеши

---

См. подробности в [BashFAQ/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), а также сразу [BashFAQ/024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)